# P Trap? Ugly mess? Not much room to work with up there

Tags: plumbing

[image: closeup][underneath[![side][2]][2]Recently decided to replace the drain in my bathroom and learned a little about p traps from the inter web.  All the work was done by the previous owner.  Was wondering if this is an acceptable configuration to act as a trap?  Not too happy about how they cut into the ceiling joist either.  Not a lot of room to work up there.[From underneath[image: Underneath]

Comment: I posted a different pic that shows how the"p trap"  is dipping down and then goes back up to the sewer line.  Wondering if this is an acceptable way or is there a better way to do it.  The drain is coming from my tub.

Comment: If it were me, I'd replace it while I had it open. Galvanized pipe tends to look like a block artery after a while, so I personally replace it whenever I see it.  Those Fernco couplings are great in a pinch, but I personally wouldn't use them in a closed up wall or ceiling.  While you're there, you might as well redo it.

Comment: The pipes are in the ceiling of my unfinished basement so urgency isn't an issue.  It's my first go at any plumbing project and I'm learning a lot.  Everything is accessible so that will make things a bit better.  Are there adapters that will attach from the little drain pipe to the final galvanized sewer pipe.  Or should I get rid of the final sewer pip and run pvc pipe all the way back to the tree going into the ground?  Thanks!

Comment: Personally I'd install PVC as far as your comfort level and budget allow.